# laravel toArray() taking too long

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code, and I'm trying to populate an json because this is an API.

```
$mids   = Message::where('sender', $user)
                    ->orWhere('receipient', $user)
                    ->lists('mid');

$last   = Message::whereIn('mid', $mids)->orderBy('mid', 'desc')->first();
$final  = $last->toArray();
return $final;
```

If I dont make the $last to array then it will just return something like:

```
"incrementing": true,
"timestamps": true,
"exists": true
```

But when I add the toArray() function it just keeps loading and loading until the server says execution time exceeded. Why?

---

**additional info**

This code is in a model and its `getLastMsgAttribute` and I appends `last_msg`

Comment: `toArray` runs both `attributesToArray()` and `relationsToArray()` and just merges the 2 arrays. You could try to run them separately (they're both public methods) and see if that works, it may help with debugging what's going wrong.

Comment: @FDL `relationsToArray()` loads the page, `attributesToArray()` doesnt, it just keeps loading.

Comment: Just as a sidenote, I would suggest checking than $mids is not an empty array. If $mids in an empty array, your whereIn constraint will throw an SQLException.

Answer (score 2):

As @naththedeveloper mentioned toArray will determine the attributes and relations that need to be retrieved in order to convert the collection to a model. Our issue was that we had 3 mutators on the Model (e.g. getSomeAttribute), one of them was performing a DB query for each model which meant 2000 queries (all of which were actually duplicates).

So check your attributes and relations

Also look into [resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-resources#writing-resources) as I think this allows you to define your own toArray method so you can select only the fields you need for your final array.

You might also be able to just use Laravel's collection "pluck" method.